# Determining file size in Perl doesn't always work

Tags: perl, file

I'm trying to enumerate directory content and check the sizes of the files there (no recursion). So I `opendir`/`readdir` through the directory, skip certain types of files (directories and such), and by using something like `my $size = -s "$file_path` get the size of the current file.

However, I'm having a weird situation - in one directory I can't get the size of any file (containing all `.exe` files). The same program runs fine on another directory (`.txt` files, `.pl` and similar).

If I copy some `.exe` file from the first directory to the other one, its size is properly determined.

If I run the program on the first directory again, the size of that one copied `.exe` is properly determined, all others still fail. So it seems like some weird caching problem.

Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: With the `-f` check, the `.exe` files for which size check doesn't work are not `plain files`. However they "become" plain files if I just copy them from that directory somewhere. Then the size check works

The part of the code used for enumerating files:

```
my $dir_handle;
my $dir_entry;


my $retVal = opendir($dir_handle, "$path");
if (!$retVal)
{
    print "Unable to open directory. \n$!";
    exit(0);
}


while ($dir_entry = readdir($dir_handle))
{
    print "Current file: $dir_entry \n";
    next if (! -f $dir_entry);
    my $size_bytes = -s "$dir_entry";

    if ($size_bytes)
    {
        print "Size: $size_bytes \n";
    }

}

closedir($dir_handle);
```

Comment: `-f $file_path or die "no such file";`

Comment: Given the EXE reference, you're probably on Windows.  Are you having trouble in one of the directories (like "My Pictures")  that are part of a "Library", which are treated differently?  That should only affect Explorer, though, not Perl or other DOS-based interactions.

Comment: Could you show more of the code where you are opening and reading the dir, building your file list?  I could try this in an all-EXE dir too.

Comment: @jimtut Yes, it's on windows, but the directories checked are just regular directories - both on local filesystem, same partition. About two directories away :)

Comment: Paul and Kenster beat me to it, but I was going to post something similar, although I often prefer to add `chdir($path) or die "$!\n"'` near the beginning, instead of messing around with the paths in the while loop.

Comment: Cool tip for the `chdir`, it can make stuff easier, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readdir()` returns the file name *only*, and doesn't include the path information - so if the directory is not the same as the current working dir, this will fail.

You want to include the path:

```
while ($dir_entry = readdir($dir_handle))
{
    print "Current file: $dir_entry \n";
    next if (! -f "$path/$dir_entry");
    my $size_bytes = -s "$path/$dir_entry";

    if ($size_bytes)
    {
        print "Size: $size_bytes \n";
    }
}
```

(and yes, using Unix-style path separators works fine here; feel free to use `\` instead if you like escaping things)

Comment: YES! Finally, I totally missed the fact that I was calling it for the current directory in one example, and some random one in the other.. I prepended the path information and the universe is back in order, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`readdir` only returns the name of each directory entry. It doesn't include the path to the directory being read. For example, if you're reading `/var/tmp` and that directory contains a file named `foo`, then readdir is going to return `foo`, not `/var/tmp/foo`.

To check whether a directory entry is a file or to get its size, you have to provide a full pathname to the file, including the directory part. Unless you're specifically calling `readdir` on the current directory, you will need to convert each filename to a pathname:

```
while ($dir_entry = readdir($dir_handle))
{
    my $pn = $path . '/' . $dir_entry;
    print "Current file: $pn \n";
    next if (! -f $pn);
    my $size_bytes = -s $pn;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're right, that was the cause of my headache, forgot to prepend the path to the directory entry and in one case it was the current directory so it happened to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As has already been stated, your bug was in not including the path information during your file operations.

I would recommend using [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) to make your file and directory operations cross platform compatible, but also to automatically handle issues like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;

my $path = '.';

my $dir = dir($path);

for my $child ( $dir->children ) {
    printf "Current file: %s\n", $child->basename;

    next if !-f $child;

    if ( my $size = -s $child ) {
        print "Size: $size\n";
    }
}
```